# How do I get flask-admin to allow inline editing PostgreSQL JSONB field using peewee model?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, peewee, flask-admin

I have a flask app with a peewee model that is using flask-admin. I want to enable the editing of JSONB fields in the popup. I have set column_editable_list to the JSONB field in my model:

```
class AuthModelView(AuthMixinView, BaseModelView):
    column_editable_list = ('attrs',)
```

The JSONB field itself is declared:

```
attrs = BinaryJSONField()
```

I'm not sure what I have to do to get the JSON to show up in the editable popup instead of the [object Object].

[image]

I tried defining **str**, **unicode**, and **repr** methods on the model containing the JSONB attrs but that didn't work. Do I have to define a custom XEditableWidget?

It's worth noting that the edit form is able to display and edit the JSON:

[image]

I don't see why the inline form doesn't use the same field type mapping?

Comment: I added hstore support pretty recently here: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/pull/1158

However, we still need to add JSON support. I think it's going to be similar to hstore support, but it's going to require some modifications to the form.js javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually don't need key, values split in label/edit form from the JSON as I saw in your pull request. I just need to make the JSON string editable as the non-inline form does in the screenshot above. I suspect that's a conditional and a few lines of javascript or a little coercing here: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/2a724048fe0c9dd8f6723e6540ce4687845170a9/flask_admin/model/widgets.py#L67-L95

Answer (score 2):

This feature was added here: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/pull/1245

It's on the current master branch and should go out with the 1.4.0 release.